# Проблема с Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, visual-studio-code

Я взял код из видео про создание клона zoom.На видео автор вводит nodemon и у него создается сайт в интернете. Я сделал точно так как он но когда ввожу nodemon показывает ошибку.
Ссылка на видео--https://youtu.be/InK2Zkobgp8
Код:

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express();
const index = require("http").server(app);
const { v4:uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const io  = require("socket.io")(server);

app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/",(req,rsp)=>{
    resizeBy.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
});

app.get("/:room",(req,res)=>{
    rsp.render("room",{roomId:req.params.room});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3030);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из видимых проблем - названия переменных. А так же пробел после require в первой строке (скорее всего в нем и проблема).

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const index = require("http").server(app);
const { v4:uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const io  = require("socket.io")(server);

app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
});

app.get("/:room", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("room", {roomId: req.params.room});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3030);
```

Comment: Я вот просто не особо помню, можно ли пробел ставить после названия функции.. Судя по ошибке дело именно в require, но .index сбивает.. Довольно мало знаком с нодой, чтобы знать о таких тонкостях.